# Como colocar Alert no PHP?

Tags: php

CODE:

```
        //Comando SQL Upadte para Atualizar os dados
        $sql = "UPDATE clientes set nome='$nome',cpf='$cpf',email='$email',setor='$setor',rua='$rua',numero='$numero',telefone='$telefone' WHERE id='$codigo'";
         //Testa o comando SQL
         mysql_query($sql) or die("Não foi possivel exercutar o comando Sql");
         //Mensagem de Sucesso na operação
         echo "O arquivo foi Alterado com sucesso";
         //Fechar a conexão
         mysql_close($conn);
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "não houve conexão com o banco";
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

acho que isso resolve:

```
echo "<script>alert('Mensagem');</script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Fica assim, sendo duas linguagens que trabalham em lados diferentes, esta é a unica forma directa...

```
   //Comando SQL Upadte para Atualizar os dados
     $sql = "UPDATE clientes set nome='$nome',cpf='$cpf',email='$email',setor='$setor',rua='$rua',numero='$numero',telefone='$telefone' WHERE id='$codigo'";
     //Testa o comando SQL
     mysql_query($sql) or die("Não foi possivel exercutar o comando Sql");
     //Mensagem de Sucesso na operação
     echo "O arquivo foi Alterado com sucesso";
     //Fechar a conexão
     mysql_close($conn);
}
else 
{
    echo "<script>alert('não houve conexão com o banco');</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é muito legal fazer alertas assim, seria mais interessante colocar este aquivo para ser acessado via requisição ajax.

O formulário Html manda via ajax as informações para serem utilizadas na query, e o arquivo php retorna um json, como retorno para o HTML.

Por padrão não tem como dar um alert no php. Dos jeitos abordados anteriormente funcionar, mas não acho seja interessante.